# Trying to read Excel data using java

Tags: java, excel

```
  import java.io.*;
  import jxl.*;
  import jxl.write.*;
  class Exc
  {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
       InputStream input = new FileInputStream("sample.xls");
       POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input); 
       Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
       Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
       Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
       Cell cell = row.getCell(10);
       if (cell == null)
      cell = row.createCell(10);
      cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
      cell.setCellValue("Data");
      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("sample.xls");
      wb.write(fileOut);
      fileOut.close();
     }
   }
```

This is simple code where I am just replacing the data in a cell. When i execute it I get this error:

`Exc.java:13: error: cannot find symbol Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);`

What does the error mean? I have placed the `jxl.jar` file in the correct path and executed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you imported the class Workbook?

Comment: Java is saying that that it can't find Workbook class, even though you say you have the jar file in the correct path. You need to double check why java is not able to find the jar file. See if the Class is present in the jar in the first place and second, instantiate some other class in the jar file and see if you get the same error. if you do, you need to google and understand out how to add external libraries to java build path.

Comment: Yes. In jxl.jar it is present. Not only getting for Workbook. Also getting the same error for Cell and Sheet too. I have checked using java -jar jxl.jar ! The class files are present.

Comment: u can use apache poi jars that is much more easy

Answer (score 0):

`WorkbookFactory` is not a JExcel API class. It belongs to Apache POI.

So, instead of this

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("sample.xls");
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input); 
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
```

Use JExcel API's [Workbook.getWorkbook()](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook(java.io.File)) method as

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("sample.xls"));
```

Comment: Thank You so much Ravi. But i am getting the same errors for Row, Cell and Sheet too.

Comment: Your whole program is written using Apache POI. Either add those jars or rewrite the program using JExcel API. Take a look at http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html